# Class based condition SCSS / SASS

Tags: class, sass, ancestor

I want to change a color based on the ancestor class. 
What I want to obtain in CSS :

```
section.container-story .story-head .content h2 {
    color:#FF0000;
}
section.container-story.category_1 .story-head .content h2 {
    color:#00FF00;
}
```

My SCSS code

```
section.container-story{

    $story-color: #FF0000;

    .story-head{

        .content{

            h2{
                color: $story-color;

                .category_1 &{
                    color: #00FF00;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Here is my non working pen : https://codepen.io/will83/pen/pwNzzQ

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `&` character.

```
$story-color: #FF0000;

.story-head{
  .content{
    h2{
      section.container-story &{
        color: $story-color;
      }
      section.container-story.category_1 &{
        color: #00FF00; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I need to rewrite the entire tree ? In fact I'm looking for a nicer way, if its exists

Comment: Although this is a quick workaround for the problem. But I am still searching for another way.

Comment: Ok thank you ! But I lost my section.container-story ancestor for .story-head and others below...

Comment: No you haven't lost the ancestor. It's just defined in a different way.